# Did the Latin '-que' mean "any, also, ever'?

Tags: proto-indo-european, latin

> [ubiquity (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ubiquity&allowed_in_frame=0) [...] + *que* "any, also, and, ever," as a suffix giving universal meaning to the word it is attached to, from PIE root * *kwe* "and."

Did Etymonline err? I know that *-que* is [an enclitic, and not a word](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6973/can-the-latin-word-que-coordinate-two-propositions#comment16759_6973).
[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-que) attests *-que* to mean only 'and', as does [AHI](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html#kwe) for the PIE  root * *kwe*.

Comment: *-que* is attached to the **word** *ubi*.

Comment: Etymonline is wrong to call PIE * *kwe* a "root", but is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 2):

-que has generalising force only after pronouns and adverbs, e.g. ubique 'wherever', quisque 'whoever'.

Answer (score 1):

I looked it up in Pons online Latin-German. There are so many translations of *-que* there, including some in which *and* simply doesn't work at all as a substitute, that any dictionary that presents *and* as the only translation must be considered incomplete.

*Also* is essentially a synonym of *and* when connecting two sentences. Since *-que* can be used in this way, it is not at all surprising that *also* made it on the list.

Fdb has explained where the translation *-ever* comes from. This explanation could also justify *any-*, since *ubique* can also be translated as *anywhere*. There may well be a better separate explanation for that, but I haven't found one.

Comment: This is not exactly an explanation, but: Additive particles (*and*, *also*) develop free choice meanings (*any*-, -*ever*) quite often in the languages of the world -- for instance, as diverse as Greek, Korean, Quichua and Adyghe.

Comment: @IanKapitonov: Yes, intuitively I don't find this surprising at all.

Comment: Right. The question is, precisely what semantics lies behind this :-)

Answer (score -1):

In early PIE the full form of the clitic was ***-q̆et***, it is a root meaning "a pair", other words with it include

***q̆eta̯*** pair

***q̆etea̯ti*** counts

***q̆etu̯ores*** four

This is a very ancient root, which meant quite the same (a pair) as early as Proto-Eurasiatic.

Comment: "Proto-Eurasiatic" is a myth.